# How to nullify an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

having an array:

```
char* arr[some_size] = {nullptr};
```

and later initializing some of its elem's is there any way that I can reset this array in other way than iterate over its elements and set them to nullptr?
I would like to avoid this:

```
for(unsigned i = 0; i < some_size;++i)
{
arr[i] = nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either iterate over it yourself, or you can call a function that iterates over it for you:

```
#include <algorithm>

// choose either one:
std::fill_n(arr, some_size, nullptr);
std::fill(arr, arr + some_size, nullptr);
```

One way or another, iteration must occur.

Comment: funny that there isn't same way of nullifying array after this array had been initialized. I can do this: T* arr[size] = {nullptr}; but later after this array has been initialized I cannot to arr[size] = {nullptr};

Comment: @Nawaz I'm more than happy to use more modern ver, so in this sense I don't see a problem.

Comment: Iteration still occurs when you initialize it, SmallB. It's just that the compiler generates the code for it instead of you or the standard-library authors.

Answer (score 4):

Rob's answer will work for C++.  If you're doing straight up C, look into memset() or bzero().

```
char *arr[size] = { NULL };
...
memset(arr, 0, sizeof(char *) * size);
/* or */
bzero(arr, sizeof(char *) * size);
```

`memset` (standard C) is generally preferred over `bzero` (being a BSD-ism).

Comment: The (minor) problem either of those functions is that we have to assume a null pointer is represented by all-bits-zero, which isn't necessarily the case.

Comment: @Rob, while technically true, can you think of any architecture where it is not zero?

Comment: @Eda, please see [comp.lang.c FAQ 5.17](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html). They're not common systems, which is why I said this is a *minor* problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Cuthbert's answer is good. 
There is also the ZeroMemory WinAPI function (For windows).